COUNTIF that uses Dropdown Values in the Formula
I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheet to keep track of how many shirts I need to order, for a Cross Country Camp.  I wanted to use a COUNTIF to count how many of each type of shirt I need to order, but I put the shirt sizes in a dropdown.  One of my formulas is =COUNTIF('Camp Roster'!H2:H17,"YLg").  It returns 0, even though there is 1 person with the shirt size.  If I hand type the sizes, instead of using the dropdown, then the formula works.  Is there a way to have the formula work with the dropdown options?  Thanks

It should work. It's possible there is a variation between the two values (space?) that isn't apparent. To confirm the values are the same, fill in  a cell with a manual value (eg A1 and a cell with the drop down value (eg. B1) and test if they are the same: =A1=B1 if the answer is false they don't match and you need to look at the values more closely. eg. "YLg"<>"YLg "

Use query() to get a table that lists all chosen sizes and their counts, like this:
=query( 
  Camp Roster'!H1:H, 
  "select Col1, count(Col1) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1", 
  1 
)

See query().
